# Which IDE is same as Visual Studio IDE for Comparing the latest document changes for wordpress?

Tags: php, ide, wordpress, comparison

I am looking same like a Visual Studio IDE for Comparing the latest document changes.
refer image [image]

But Visual studio did not support PHP. So I am looking same functionality in any IDE which is suitable for Xampp and WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open PHP files in VS, and I expect the comparison function will still work.

However, and generic text comparison approach is to use Notepad++ with the Compare plugin:

http://www.technicaloverload.com/compare-two-files-using-notepad/

If you want a PHP IDE, Eclipse will allow you to compare files too (Compare With Other Resource function):

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2018-09/r/eclipse-ide-php-developers